# Regex in google script to retrieve digits after specific words

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have a google app script that parses some pdfs and I started with the following regex, that retrieves the 5 sets of 3digits from `Reference` tag:

```
[w,W,s,S]*(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3})
```

I added to it more versatility to also retrieve 9 digits combination for `Reference` tag;

```
[w,W,s,S]*(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3})?.?(\d{3})?
```

Both versions only match the digits, no words, which is perfect.

**I would like to also retrieve the digits related to `Amount` tag, while ignoring any words and digits in between. And it's here that I'm having some trouble.**

I tried:

```
.*?(?:Ref)(?:.*:) ? ?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3})?.?(\d{3})?
```

But it already starts to include the word.

This is some dummy text example of the text where the regex is being used:

- can have more words after each "tag" (example: *`Reference of something`* // *`Amount of first payment`*:)
- can have `:` or not

  ```
  Some dummy text that may have words in common like `reference` or `amount` throughout the document

  Reference: 245 154 343 345 345
  Entity: 34567    
  Amount: 11,11
  Payment date: 14/07/2022

  Some more text
  ```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
^Reference:?[\t ]+(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})(?:\n(?!Amount)\S.*)*\nAmount:?[\t ]+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8cZ3z/1).

Or taking `Reference of something // Amount of first payment:` into account, you might use `[^\d\n]*` to match any character except digits or newlines:

```
 ^Reference\b[^\d\n]*[\t ](\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})(?:\n(?!Amount\b)\S.*)*\nAmount\b[^\d\n]*[\t ](\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Reference\b` Match the word `Reference`
- `[^\d\n]*[\t ]` Match optional chars other than a digit or newline and then match either a space or tab *(You could also use `\s*` but that could also possible match a newline)*
- `(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})[\t ]*(\d{3})` Match capture **group 1** to capture **group 5** containing digits with either a space or tab in between
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!Amount\b)` Match a newline and assert not the word `Amount` to the right
  - `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char followed by the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\nAmount\b` Match a newline and the word `Amount`
- `[^\d\n]*[\t ]` Match optional chars other than a digit or newline and then match either a space or tab
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture **group 6**, match 1+ digits and optionally a comma with 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/57s6wW/1).

Comment: thank you for your input. Nevertheless, this brings the same problems I was facing because when I use the regex on my script, I get the full match (words + digits) when I just want the digits. I either have to adjust regex or adjust the script somehow to be able to use the capture groups and not the full match.

Comment: @user1128912 In the script that you are using, can you extract the capture group values? What is the script that you are using?

Comment: this is the script I'm using. Maybe I should find a way to either use each capture group and join data in the end, because with some minor adjustments your code does work on regex101. 'function extractPDFtext(text){
  const regexp = /[w,W,s,S]*(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3}).?(\d{3})?.?(\d{3})?[\w\W]*?(\d+.\d+)/gm;
  try{
    let array = [...text.match(regexp)];
    return array;
  }catch(e){
    let array = ["No items found"] 
    return array;
  }
};'

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct because with some minor tweaks, the regex retrieved what I wanted and I also updated the script (which was not part of the request)